# How to parse UUID from PHP to JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to parse UUID from database to javascript function in order to open the invoice on blank page and then get the ID from link. Problem is when I do this with table id which is a number (like `34, 76` etc.) it works fine, but when I try to get UUID which is something like (
`2BC9C179-F908-45A9-826D-99097A5E1FD0`) I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`

PHP

```
<td>
 <span class="table-remove">
  <button type="button"class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0" onclick="updateInvoice(<?php echo $row['GId']?>)">Güncelle</button>
 </span>
</td>
```

JavaScript

```
function updateInvoice(ID){
 window.open('update.php?invoice_id=' + ID, '_blank');
 }
```

I tried to use stringify method but it didn't work.

Comment: Put single quote 
   `onclick="updateInvoice('<?php echo $row['GId']?>')" `

Comment: Probably you want `onclick="updateInvoice('<?php echo $row['GId']?>')"`, i.e. use single commas when calling the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use with single quote

```
onclick="updateInvoice('<?php echo $row['GId']?>')"
```